# Normalizing sum of radial basis functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

I am trying to simulate decision making using a sum of 3-dimensional radial basis functions.

I have $n\in [1,\infty]$ radial basis functions like

$f_i(x,y,z) = A_i\ \exp\left(-\left(\dfrac{(x-\mu_{i,x})^{2}}{2 \sigma _{i,x}^{2}} + \dfrac{(y-\mu_{i,y})^{2}}{2 \sigma _{i,y}^{2}} + \dfrac{(z-\mu_{i,z})^{2}}{2 \sigma _{i,z}^{2}}\right)\right)$

$g(x,y,z) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x,y,z)$

where $x,y,z \in [0,1]$

and $\mu\in[0,1],\, \sigma\in(0,\infty],\, A\in[-1,1]$

$x$, $y$ and $z$ are the inputs to this decision making process and for each function f i have seven parameters ($A_i,\mu_{i,x},\mu_{i,y},\mu_{i,z},\sigma_{i,x},\sigma_{i,y},\sigma_{i,z}$) to vary. A high value of $g(x,y,z)$ means one decision and a low value means another. Later on I plan to apply evolutionary learning to these parameters to see if that can improve decision making.

To make this learning efficient however, the function should have the codomain $[-1,1]$ and when fed with randomized input (from $[0,1]$) there should be 50% positive and 50% negative outputs.

I suppose I have to do something like:

$$g'(x,y,z) = \frac{g(x,y,z) + a}{b}$$

but how should I set a and b?

PS. computation time is a factor in this application so an analytical solution would be much more valuable than a numerical one

**EDIT**

If I drop the requirement of having 50% positive and 50% negative solutions, is it easier to solve the problem then?